# Centering: display table and img with max-width

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've an issue on Internet Explorer 11 and lower.

Centralize a box with display table is easy. The problem is when your "main" element inside this box is an image.

In Desktops sizes, works fine, but, in responsive, the max-width from image doesn't work. Of course, trying to get max-width from a box with display: table don't have no sense. Thinking about that, i've tried a lot of another properties, but no success.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/v2f73uk8/ (Test on  IE)

```
figure{
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

figcaption{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    -webkit-opacity: 0.5;
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    -ms-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This example is basically what my problem is. The figcaption size have to be the same as image / figure. If I delete the display table, the figcaption gets the width from figure (in this case, 100% / block).

The real deal to fix this, is set an max-width and width: 100% to the figure (like the **wrap** trick), BUT, if i do that, this will never get dynamical width.

What i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inline-block` inseated of `table`. That way the figure will always get the same width as the image. And set `max-width: 100%;` to make it responsive.

Demo, http://jsfiddle.net/v2f73uk8/1/

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

figure{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto; /*no need this anymore*/
    max-width: 100%;
}

figcaption{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    -webkit-opacity: 0.5;
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    -ms-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Note, I add `text-align: center;` to the `<body>` in order to get the `<figure>` centered.

Tested works even back to IE9.

Comment: Wow, you rock the boat! I've tried the inline-block with text-center, but i forgot to add max-width to the figure, damn! Thank you bro!